# Build docker image in jenkins

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I deployed jenkins on my local computer(os:windows10) as docker image after that i create an item as freestyle project
the pipeline is connecting to github repo that has test node project and build docker image of it
here's the pipeline :
[build docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYOOD.png)

I got this error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPc1V.png)

any help to fix this error and thanks in advance

Comment: Where do the */var/jenkins_home/workspace/test* folder come from?

Comment: @tmarouane the test folder is the project i created in jenkins ..it has the github repo's files

Comment: How did you create the folder in jenkins? Could you please add all the steps including how you ran Jenkins, Dockefile or container images used if any...